# Is there a way to fake a server address to get json output?

Tags: android, json

I'm building an android app and I want to get some json output from a server and display relevant information. The problem the actual json data source only prints json if the request is coming form the same host. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: I guess there's a reason why the server won't send data to outer source, right?

Comment: You could try setting the Referer header to the host, are you not in control of the host data?

Comment: It gps bus data from a transit agency so no I'm not in control of the host

Comment: hapman: The only way I know of to get "around this" would be IP address spoofing, which probably isn't possible on Android and may be against the law in some jurisdictions. If you work for the transit agency, get them to expose the "actual JSON data source" as a public Web service.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, it's not a must have feature as my app is already on the market. I do have friends that work there but they can only do so much as they aren't in a position of power. It sucks that any public agency would hide their data.